# Disable GRUB and use Apple's EFI-bootloader on MacBook Pro

Tags: grub2, mac, macbook-pro

How do I remove GRUB? I'm asking because I'm using a MacBook Pro and when I boot my computer, it asks me first to choose from OS-X or Ubuntu (through Apple’s EFI-bootloader) and the second time through Ubuntu’s GRUB bootloader.

Any tips for how I can fully disable GRUB?

Answer (score 1):

You can make GRUB not appear and simply boot your first OS choice by [setting GRUB_TIMEOUT=0 in `/etc/default/grub`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Setup#Configuring_GRUB_2):

1. Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
2. Run `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`
3. Change the `GRUB_TIMEOUT` line to `GRUB_TIMEOUT=0`
4. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to save
5. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit
6. Run `sudo update-grub`